# Could vs Be able to

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I saw a grammar question about this issue :"He ........ arrive at the party on time, even after missing the train, so he was very pleased." and the website picked "was able to" as the answer. I was wondering about other true answers.Is "could" a correct answer for this question?

Comment: There could be many fill-ins, but usually you have to select from given options. By context, we know that he reached the party on time. By contrast, *could* means it is possible (in theory) to arrive on time. Since *was able to* means that he did in fact arrive on time, that fits best. Remember, that language is not all right or all wrong, but has shades of meaning. The best answer makes the richest sentence.

Comment: That's just the answer the test-maker had in mind, and therefore it's the only correct one. Never mind the reason and never mind the context. Multiple choice language tests are not designed for education, but for sorting and ranking.

Comment: Thank you very much @Yosef Baskin.

Comment: "[He checked the bus timetables.] He could [still] arrive at the party on time, even after missing the train, so he was relieved." is quite unremarkable. But it's difficult to fit 'very pleased' in sensibly.